# Returning boolean from oracle function or procedure with out parameter

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, return, out

I need to develop a web application with `php`.For login process , .Normally I would use select statement with id and password , if row returns then it is successful login.But I want to use stored procedure and don't want to get any row from database but simple `boolean` value.The signature of `PL/SQL` process is below.

```
procedure successful_login(cit_id in citizens.citizen_id%type,
                           pass in varchar2,v_login_successful out boolean)
```

I won't bloat page with code but procedure changes `v_login_successful` to true or false depending on successful login, in PL/SQL.But I want to call this procedure from PHP.If I bind a php variable to `v_login_successful` parameter and execute procedure from PHP, will PL/SQL engine return changed version of `v_login_successful` variable back to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL has [Boolean datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS348), but SQL doesn't have. Which means, you can

1. use it in functions, procedures, anonymous blocks.
2. use it as parameters in procedures and functions, only if they are used in PL/SQL context.

When you are calling the procedure from php, it will be a sql statement. You will get, `expression is of wrong type` exception.

Instead, you can use `CHAR(1)` (Y or N) or `NUMBER(1)` (0 or 1) datatype for out parameter.